# Listview Empty View is always shown

Tags: android, listview, parse-platform

I use a custom [ParseQueryAdapter](https://parse.com/docs/android/api/com/parse/ParseQueryAdapter.html) to load data in listview. I want to show a message when there is no data but the message is shown even when data are not empty. I think it is due to the fact that data are not yet loaded. I tried with `setEmptyView` and also with a test on the adapter `if mAdapter.isEmpty()`.

I tried waiting a few seconds before testing if adapter is empty but although it works, I think it's not a good practice.

My custom adapter where I make the query:

```
public class CategoryEventsAdapter extends ParseQueryAdapter<Event> {

    public CategoryEventsAdapter(Context context, final String c) {

    super(context, new ParseQueryAdapter.QueryFactory<Event>() {

            public ParseQuery<Event> create() {
                ParseQuery<Event> query = new ParseQuery<Event>("Event");
                query.whereEqualTo("published", true);
                query.whereEqualTo("category", c);
                return query;
            }
        });
    }

    @Override
    public View getItemView(Event event, View v, ViewGroup parent) {
        ...
    }
}
```

And I simply call it in a Fragment:

```
mAdapter = new CategoryEventsAdapter(getActivity(), category);
listview.setAdapter(mAdapter);
if (mAdapter.isEmpty()) {
    // show message
}
```

Comment: can you post your ListView layout and how you set the empty view?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've never used this particular part of Parse but looking at the docs, the query seems to be async. Instead you can try this maybe:

```
mAdapter = new CategoryEventsAdapter(getActivity(), category);

// add a listener for when the query is done.
mAdapter.addOnQueryLoadListener(new OnQueryLoadListener<ParseObject>() {
    public void onLoaded(List<ParseObject> objects, ParseException e) {
        // Check if empty here and show message.
        if (objects.size == 0){
            // show message
        }
    }
});

listview.setAdapter(mAdapter);
```

So once the query is done, it should call `onLoaded` so then you can determine if it is empty or not. In `onLoaded` you can check the count of the `objects` parameter. Not sure if it's already set in the adapter if you do `mAdapter.isEmpty` at that point.

Answer (score 0):

This is my ParseQueryAdapter implementation that lets you choose an "empty" placeholder. You just call `adapter.setEmptyLayoutId(R.layout.empty)` from outside.

```
public class ParseAdapter extends ParseQueryAdapter {

    private final static int EMPTY_VIEW = 2;
    private int emptyViewLayoutId;
    private boolean isEmpty;

    public ParseAdapter(Context c, QueryFactory<? extends ParseObject> q) {
        super(c, q);

        addOnQueryLoadListener(new OnQueryLoadListener() {
            @Override
            public void onLoading() {
                isEmpty = false;
            }

            @Override
            public void onLoaded(List list, Exception e) {
                if (list == null || list.size() == 0) {
                    isEmpty = true;
                }
            }
        });
    }

    @Override
    public void notifyDataSetChanged() {
        isEmpty = false;
        super.notifyDataSetChanged();
    }

    public void setEmptyLayoutId(int emptyViewLayoutId) {
        this.emptyViewLayoutId = emptyViewLayoutId;
    }


    @Override
    public View getItemView(ParseObject object, View v, ViewGroup parent) {
        if (isEmpty) {
            v = View.inflate(getContext(), emptyViewLayoutId, null);
            return v;
        }

        v = v != null ? v : View.inflate(getContext(), rowLayoutId, null);
        //do whatever you want on v
        return v;
    }

    @Override
    public int getViewTypeCount() {
        return super.getViewTypeCount() + 1; //3
    }

    @Override
    public int getItemViewType(int position) {
        return isEmpty ? EMPTY_VIEW : super.getItemViewType(position);
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return isEmpty ? 1 : super.getCount();
    }
}
```

You need to add an item view type because otherwise, if empty, `getItemView()` won't be called in some cases. Overriding `getCount()` to return 1 is not enough, because `ParseQueryAdapter` performs some checks over the view type inside `getView()`, and won't pass the call to `getItemView()`.